# ASMX in Delphi Studio

Tags: delphi, plugins, asmx

I recently bought Bob's book [Delphi XML, SOAP & Web Services](http://www.lulu.com/content/paperback-book/delphi-xml-soap-and-web-services-development/5551656)

in page 85 of this book the (Delphi 2006 8used) comes with several New Item Categories such as

- C# Projects
- C++ Builder projects
- Delphi for .NET Projects

something that you don't have in a fresh installation

I need this **ASP.NET Web Service Application** that is inside Delphi for .NET Projects, but I can't find how do we get this plugin(?) to install in Delphi so we get all this new projects categories.

Does any of you use this and can tell me what is the **Plugin**?

*image from the book showing what we are after*
[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-08-31_1322_asmx_in_delphi.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-08-31_1322_asmx_in_delphi.png)

We tried Delphi prism but it is not that as Prism works in Visual Studio it self and not in Delphi Studio.

We also tried to send an email to **[Bob Swart](http://www.drbob42.com/)** but no answer from him :(

We thought and we own [RAD Studio 2007 Professional](http://www.drbob42.com/d4dn/index.htm), and that comes with that **Delphi for .NET Projects** but not the ASP.NET Web Services, so, we are thinking that it only be available for the Enterprise or Architect versions, but I can't find any information regarding where is this (bundle details and what's inside what) :(

Thanks

Comment: balexandre, go to "C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\ObjRepos\DelphiDotNet" and check the existence of the WebService.asmx.pas file.

Comment: Here you can find the feature matrix http://www.ibase.ru/prices/radstudio-2007-datasheet.pdf of Rad Studio 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.... (finally)

The best way to integrate Delphi code in a .NET output (in my case ASP.NET Web Services) is to download **[Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism)** ([free trial version for evaluation](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/delphi_prism)) and use it.

File > New Website > ASP.NET Web Service > Language: Oxygene > Choose the required Framework

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-01_0857.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-01_0857.png)

This will create a normal ASMX Web Service with the .pas file as the Code Behind :)

Exactly what I'm after!

Comment: I strongly suggest you create a new _project_, not a new web site. The Web Site Project model is too simpleminded for a web service.

Answer (score 3):

The Delphi.Net functionality was removed after Delphi 2007, so I am not sure why you do not see the project type. But as Delphi.Net is a pretty dead technology it would probably make sense to look for an alternative for .Net development like Delphi Prism or C#.

Comment: Actually it's removed after Delphi 2007, Delphi 2007 was support .Net v2 while Delphi 2006 supports only .Net 1.1.

Comment: so, what you are saying Lemmy is that we should use Prism then, is that it?

Comment: Mohammed: Oh sorry I didn't know Delphi 2007 still had it. 
balexandre: I'd just suggest not to use Delphi.Net because that is a dead-end. If you want to do asmx, pick Delphi Prims, C#, VB.Net or any other .Net language you feel comfortable with.

Comment: the idea was to use pascal but outputs an ASP.NET Web Service and not that 'stupid' ISAPI DLL :)
so we can reuse plenty of code already written in pascal. We really do not want to create new code (as I'm a C#/VB developer it would be extremely painful to rewrite everything again, tested, etc ...)

Comment: well in that case Delphi Prism sounds like the logical way to go for you. But I personally have never used it so I don't know how stable and Delphi-compatible it is. You'll surely have issues with several things like string indices (0-based in .NET, 1-based in Delphi, Garbage Collection and missing framework classes), but someone with more experience with Delphi Prism can surely better explain how bad those pain points are in real life. Delphi.Net surely has fewer of those painpoints, but its compatibility to class Delphi really constrained it too much. Thats why it ultimately failed.

Comment: Lemmy: you should consider correcting your answer (the goal of SO is to have correct answers).

Comment: so, the bottom line is... There is no Good support for pascal code in order to build ASMX Services, we should do everything from scratch again using ... PRISM? so why prism? and not just plain old Visual Studio ASP.NET Web Service project in C#/VB ?

Comment: I agree with balexandre. I don't see a strong advantage in Prism. And if you go with VS, you still don't have to like it. As long as it is only easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since Delphi 2007, the functionality has been split into three different product, plus a fourth studio product. There's Delphi for WIN32 which includes C++ and Delphi for .NET which includes C# and ASP.NET. And then there's the Developers Studio which combines these development systems into one product. There are also products called Turbo Delphi, Turbo C++, Turbo C# and Turbo Delphi for .NET.

To be honest, Borland/Codegear/Embarcadero is trying to find the most popular combinations of these products making it very unclear for developers to choose the right version. Now we have Delphi Prism for .NET which integrates in Visual Studio, plus Delphi and Delphi for .NET or whatever. Anyway, I stopped upgrading Delphi since I bought Developer Studio 2007 simply because they're making a big mess of their marketing strategy.

Plus, they're becoming too expensive. For .NET development, Visual Studio will provide plenty of options already, especially when designing web applications. I will upgrade once the price becomes reasonable again and their marketing strategy becomes more normalized. I fear it will be a cold day in Hell when that happens.

You're probably using just the WIN32 version, not the Studio version which would combine both. Or you just installed the WIN32 and not the .NET part! Or, with Delphi 2007, you just start the WIN32 identity, not the whole Studio identity. (Delphi will install multiple icons, one for Delphi/WIN32, one for C++, one for C#/.NET and one for the complete studio.)

---

Just adding that I myself use the RAD Developer Studio 2007 and it does contain the ASP.NET Web Services. Just make sure you've included them during installation!

Comment: So, in order to use pascal code that, today, outputs an ISAPI DLL Service, what will you recomend in order to reuse the same code but to output an ASMX Web Service? So I can integrate in our ASP.NET Web Site projects that we are lunching, part of a new line of products? My problem is that I want to reuse all the existing code from our Delphi developer, and slpit his work in 2, Core feature in a WebService(s) and Presentation (Delphi for Windows and ASP.NET for Web). Thank you for the tip though.